# Compare data between two Arrays containing custom Swift Objects

Tags: arrays, swift

I have some data I have received through an API that return JSON to me. I know I can fetch it and store relevant info from the API into my iOS app. But only while the app is running. I.E. I have not implemented YET how to store the info fetched from the API into UserDefalults. Working on this feature I ran into a problem.

I have two Arrays that keeps track of my data. The first Array is the Array I want to store in UserDefaults when I have fetch my data. This one is called "lenders" and keeps LenderData
The second Array is my temporary Array. It contains the same type of objects, and this is the one I want to populate with data from the API and then compare to my existing Array "lenders".

I want to check if the "lenders" Array contains any object that has the same id as the object I'm looking at in the "lendersTemp" array. If the lenders Array does not contain any LederData object with the id of the tempLender we are currently looking at, we add the tempLender into the lenders Array. How would I go about doing this?

My current (non-working) solution is as follows:

```
var lenders = [LenderData]()
var lendersTemp = [LenderData]()

...
// Get JSON DATA
...

for tempLender in self.lendersTemp {
    if !self.lenders.contains(where: {$0.id == tempLender.id}) {
        self.lenders.append(tempLender)
     }
}
```

**EDIT:**
My view did load method:

```
var lenders = [LenderData]()
var lendersTemp = [LenderData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    downloadJSON {
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }

    self.myTableView.rowHeight = 90
    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: "*store the info fetched from the API into UserDefalults"* - Don't. `UserDefaults` is not where you store app data.

Comment: Define "non-working". At first glance, the code you posted looks correct.

Comment: The wording of that sentence, may have been poor. But if not in UserDefaults, where should I store it then? It's non-working as of now, since the tableview (that worked before trying to store data in lendersTemp and comparing it to what lies in "lenders") showing me that data in "lenders" is now very empty when I build and run my code

Comment: You can write the data to a file, put it in CoreData, or a SQLite database. Use your debugger. Is `self.lenders` being updated or not? If not, see why not. If it is, then your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: alright - will do and I will return with some sort of answer :) ty!

Comment: Found it - my comparison "algorithm" was called after the reloadData on the table view due to the way I designed the getJSON function call

Comment: Glad you fixed it. You should either delete your question or post complete answer below if you think it will help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with some help! So this is my answer to my own question!

My problem was that getting data from my API is done with an asyc method. And I tried to do comparison after the reload method was called on my TableView. So I did not populate the array the tableview is getting data from, before after the `reloadData()` had been called and therefore it seemed like my tableview and comparison algorithm, did not work, when in fact it did!